# nodejs Firestore suddenly breaks: Date objects

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple node script I run to update data in a Firestore database. I used it a couple of hours ago, worked fine. Got dinner, came back, and now I get this error when I run it:

```
node ./json-to-firestore.js
```

> The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
>   AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK. To hide this warning and ensure your app does
>   not break, you need to add the following code to your app before
>   calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
>
> const firestore = new Firestore();   const settings = {/* your
>   settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
>   firestore.settings(settings);

The example provided in the error does not apply to my case. I've looked for help on this issue, but all the posts seem to be angular-specific. This is all I'm trying to do:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./service-key.json");

const data = require("./occ-firestore.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
});

data && Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    const nestedContent = data[key];

    if (typeof nestedContent === "object") {
        Object.keys(nestedContent).forEach(docTitle => {
            admin.firestore()
                .collection(key)
                .doc(docTitle)
                .set(nestedContent[docTitle])
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log("Document successfully written!");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
                });
        });
    }
});
```

I execute this script by running:

```
node ./json-to-firestore.js
```

I'm running NodeJS 8.11.3.

I checked [Google's docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) and there's no reference to this new behavior.

Can someone provide me with a suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This change has been around for a quite some time.  Perhaps you updated your client library recently?  Anyway, the suggestion is in the error message - it's quite clear.

Comment: I think this error started being thrown in firebase-admin 5.13.0

Comment: I got this too !

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your comment. I agree the message is clear, but I'm having trouble translating their recommendation for use in my code.

Comment: The message is just a warning saying that the way dates are handled has changed.  If it doesn't affect your code, then you can ignore it.  If you're expecting date object to come back for Timestamp fields, then you need to adjust your code, or add the suggested lines of code until you can accept Timestamp fields.

Comment: That's the thing... it's erroring out and not executing. My code has nothing to do with dates, so it's unclear to me why it's failing. If it was just an innocuous warning, I wouldn't be concerned.

Comment: Did you find a fix to this?

Answer (score 5):

This can be fixed as such:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
```

Comment: It worked for me when I used 'admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)});' instead  of  'admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);'

Comment: As per Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

It depends were you are connecting to Firebase from. 'admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)});' is correct if connecting from your own server, where as if you are running Firebase Functions there is no need to do this. You can just use the example in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by downgrade version firebase to this

```
{
  firebase-admin: "5.12.0",
  firebase-functions: "1.0.1"
}
```

Comment: That worked, actually... but that seems like more of a workaround than a solution. I'll want to be able to update to current versions eventually. But for now, it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is changing how Date objects are stored in Firestore. Bellow is an actual warning from them (at the date of posting this answer) whenever you try to save Date objects to Firestore:

> The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
>   AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
>   To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the
>   following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:

```
const firestore = new Firestore();
const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);
```

And more importantly, how to handle these changes so your code does not break:

> With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read back as
>   Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects. So you will also
>   need to update code expecting a Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:

```
// Old:
const date = snapshot.get('created_at');
// New:
const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');
const date = timestamp.toDate();
```